# JQL update needed

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jql

I just got put onto a project where one of the requirements have changed and I was wondering if I could simply update the functionality by changing the JQL.

I have the following table in our database:

```
select * from project_organization;

ID    PROJECT_ID   ORG_ID
1     100          1000
2     100          2000
3     200          1000
```

Our current JQL gets translated as:

```
select * from project_organization where org_id=2000

ID    PROJECT_ID   ORG_ID
2     100          2000
```

I'm trying to write a query that will pull back the following rows:

```
select po.* from project_organization po 
   LEFT JOIN project_organization po2 
   ON po.org_id=po2.org_id and ??????

ID    PROJECT_ID   ORG_ID
1     100          2000
3     200          null
```

I've tried a handful of LEFT JOIN queries but so far have been unable to get the results I am looking for.

Can anyone provide any guidance?

Comment: What is the result you actually want to get from this, your "expected results" are very vague.

Comment: Nick, I am looking to have the results from the last sql query with only two rows returned (one has a null value for org_id)

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow. Based on the results of your first select, the row with `ID=3` would have an `ORG_ID` of `1000`, not `null`.

Comment: I need to do a left join (I assume) on the project_organization table so that it can pull back a list of all `PROJECT_ID`'s where the `ORG_ID` is 2000 OR just display the `PROJECT_ID` and have the `ORG_ID` be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT po.id, po.project_id, po2.org_id
FROM `project_organizations` AS po
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `project_organizations` AS po2 ON po.`project_id` = po2.`project_id` AND po2.`org_id` = 2000
    GROUP BY project_id
```

Based on the previous comments.